# Pygame - Pause menu not working?

Tags: python, python-2.7, menu, pygame, pause

**Over View**

I am at a stage where I want to add a couple of 'Extra' menus to my game. I am starting this off by creating the pause menu and plan to use the same concept to create a 'Shop' and 'Player creation' as well as a 'Mini Game'.

**Problem**

So far I have the idea of a menu, but it stop if the mouse moves, and I am not sure if it continues when continue is pressed.

**Code**

Here is my code:
    import pygame, random, time
    pygame.init()

```
#Screen
SIZE = width, height = 1280, 720 #Make sure background image is same size
SCREEN = pygame.display.set_mode(SIZE)
pygame.display.set_caption("Cube")

#Events
done = False
menu_on = True
game_start = False
pause = False

#Colors
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
GREY = (51,51,51)
YELLOW =  (255, 255, 153)
PURPLE = (153, 102, 255)
RED = (255, 0 ,0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)


#Fonts
FONT = pygame.font.SysFont("Trebuchet MS", 25)
FONT_2 = pygame.font.SysFont("Trebuchet MS", 40)
MENU_FONT = (FONT_2)
FONT_HUD = pygame.font.SysFont("Trebuchet MS", 40)

#Info
time = 0
minute = 0
hour = 0
day = 0
year = 0
counter = 0

blink_clock = 0
blink = 0

hunger = 100
fun = 100
health = 100

feeling = 3

#Hunger
HUNGERFONT = FONT_HUD.render("Hunger:{0:03}".format(hunger),1, BLACK) #zero-pad day to 3 digits
HUNGERFONTR=HUNGERFONT.get_rect()
HUNGERFONTR.center=(886, 625)

HUNGERFONT_R = FONT_HUD.render("Hunger:{0:03}".format(hunger),1, RED) #zero-pad day to 3 digits
HUNGERFONT_RR=HUNGERFONT_R.get_rect()
HUNGERFONT_RR.center=(885, 625)

HUNGERFONT_G = FONT_HUD.render("Hunger:{0:03}".format(hunger),1, GREEN) #zero-pad day to 3 digits
HUNGERFONT_GR=HUNGERFONT_G.get_rect()
HUNGERFONT_GR.center=(885, 625)

#Fun
FUNFONT = FONT_HUD.render("Fun:{0:03}".format(fun),1, BLACK) #zero-pad day to 3 digits
FUNFONTR=FUNFONT.get_rect()
FUNFONTR.center=(626, 625)

FUNFONT_R = FONT_HUD.render("Fun:{0:03}".format(fun),1, RED) #zero-pad day to 3 digits
FUNFONT_RR=FUNFONT_R.get_rect()
FUNFONT_RR.center=(625, 625)

FUNFONT_G = FONT_HUD.render("Fun:{0:03}".format(fun),1, GREEN) #zero-pad day to 3 digits
FUNFONT_GR=FUNFONT_G.get_rect()
FUNFONT_GR.center=(625, 625)

#Health
HEALTHFONT = FONT_HUD.render("Health:{0:03}".format(health),1, BLACK) #zero-pad day to 3 digits
HEALTHFONTR=HEALTHFONT.get_rect()
HEALTHFONTR.center=(366, 625)

HEALTHFONT_R = FONT_HUD.render("Health:{0:03}".format(health),1, RED) #zero-pad day to 3 digits
HEALTHFONT_RR=HEALTHFONT_R.get_rect()
HEALTHFONT_RR.center=(365, 625)

HEALTHFONT_G = FONT_HUD.render("Health:{0:03}".format(health),1, GREEN) #zero-pad day to 3 digits
HEALTHFONT_GR=HEALTHFONT_G.get_rect()
HEALTHFONT_GR.center=(365, 625)

#Year
YEARFONT = FONT.render("Year:{0:03}".format(year),1, BLACK) #zero-pad day to 3 digits
YEARFONTR=YEARFONT.get_rect()
YEARFONTR.center=(885, 20)
#Day
DAYFONT = FONT.render("Day:{0:03}".format(day),1, BLACK) #zero-pad day to 3 digits
DAYFONTR=DAYFONT.get_rect()
DAYFONTR.center=(985, 20)
#Hour
HOURFONT = FONT.render("Hour:{0:02}".format(hour),1, BLACK) #zero-pad hours to 2 digits
HOURFONTR=HOURFONT.get_rect()
HOURFONTR.center=(1085, 20)
#Minute
MINUTEFONT = FONT.render("Minute:{0:02}".format(minute),1, BLACK) #zero-pad minutes to 2 digits
MINUTEFONTR=MINUTEFONT.get_rect()
MINUTEFONTR.center=(1200, 20)


#Characters
def load_image(cube):
    image = pygame.image.load(cube)
    return image

class Menu:

    hovered = False
    def __init__(self, text, pos):
        self.text = text
        self.pos = pos
        self.set_rect()
        self.draw()
    def draw(self):
        self.set_rend()
        SCREEN.blit(self.rend, self.rect)

    def set_rend(self):
        self.rend = MENU_FONT.render(self.text, 1, self.get_color())

    def get_color(self):
        if self.hovered:
            return (PURPLE)
        else:
            return (YELLOW)

    def set_rect(self):
        self.set_rend()
        self.rect = self.rend.get_rect()
        self.rect.topleft = self.pos

class Cube_black(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Cube_black, self).__init__()
        self.images = []
        self.images.append(load_image('Cube_black.png'))

        self.index = 0
        self.image = self.images[self.index]
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(440, 180, 74, 160)

    def update(self):
        self.index += 1
        if self.index >= len(self.images):
            self.index = 0
        self.image = self.images[self.index]

class Eye_black(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Eye_black, self).__init__()
        self.images = []
        self.images.append(load_image('Eye_grey.png'))

        self.index = 0
        self.image = self.images[self.index]
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(440, 180, 74, 160)

    def update(self):
        self.index += 1
        if self.index >= len(self.images):
            self.index = 0
        self.image = self.images[self.index]

class Mood_good(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Mood_good, self).__init__()
        self.images = []
        self.images.append(load_image('Good.png'))

        self.index = 0
        self.image = self.images[self.index]
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(440, 180, 74, 160)

    def update(self):
        self.index += 1
        if self.index >= len(self.images):
            self.index = 0
        self.image = self.images[self.index]

class Mood_fine(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Mood_fine, self).__init__()
        self.images = []
        self.images.append(load_image('Fine.png'))

        self.index = 0
        self.image = self.images[self.index]
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(440, 180, 74, 160)

    def update(self):
        self.index += 1
        if self.index >= len(self.images):
            self.index = 0
        self.image = self.images[self.index]


class Blink(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Blink, self).__init__()
        self.images = []
        self.images.append(load_image('Blink.png'))

        self.index = 0
        self.image = self.images[self.index]
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(440, 180, 74, 160)

    def update(self):
        self.index += 1
        if self.index >= len(self.images):
            self.index = 0
        self.image = self.images[self.index]

class Blank(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Blank, self).__init__()
        self.images = []
        self.images.append(load_image('Blank.png'))

        self.index = 0
        self.image = self.images[self.index]
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(440, 180, 74, 160)

    def update(self):
        self.index += 1
        if self.index >= len(self.images):
            self.index = 0
        self.image = self.images[self.index]

cube_color = Cube_black()
cube = pygame.sprite.Group(cube_color)

eye_color = Eye_black()
eye = pygame.sprite.Group(eye_color)

mood_feeling_g = Mood_good()
mood_good = pygame.sprite.Group(mood_feeling_g)

mood_feeling_f = Mood_fine()
mood_fine = pygame.sprite.Group(mood_feeling_f)

blink = Blink()
blinking = pygame.sprite.Group(blink)

blankcube = Blank()
blankgroup = pygame.sprite.Group(blankcube)

start_game = [Menu("START GAME", (140, 105))]
help_ = [Menu("HELP", (140, 155))]
quit_ = [Menu("QUIT", (140, 205))]
pause = [Menu("PAUSE GAME", (140, 105))]
continue_game = [Menu("CONTINUE", (140, 55))]

#Game Speed
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
FPS = 60
CLOCKTICK = pygame.USEREVENT+1
pygame.time.set_timer(CLOCKTICK, 1000)                      

SCREEN.fill(WHITE)
while not done:

    if pause == False:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_p:
                        pause = True

    if menu_on == True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                done = True

            SCREEN.fill(GREY)

            for Menu in help_:
                if Menu.rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
                    Menu.hovered = True
                else:
                    Menu.hovered = False
                Menu.draw()

            for Menu in quit_:
                if Menu.rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
                    Menu.hovered = True
                    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                        done = True
                else:
                    Menu.hovered = False
                Menu.draw()

            for Menu in start_game:
                if Menu.rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
                    Menu.hovered = True
                    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                        game_start = True
                else:
                    Menu.hovered = False
                Menu.draw()

            cube.update()
            cube.draw(SCREEN)

            eye.update()
            eye.draw(SCREEN)

            mood_good.update()
            mood_good.draw(SCREEN)

            if blink == 1:
                blinking.update()
                blinking.draw(SCREEN)

            if event.type == CLOCKTICK:
                blink_clock = blink_clock + 1
                if blink_clock == 1:
                    blink_clock = 0
                    blink = random.randint(0, 1)
                if blink == 1:
                    blinking.update()
                    blinking.draw(SCREEN)
                    if blink_clock == 1:
                        blink = 0

            blankgroup.update()
            blankgroup.draw(SCREEN)

    if pause == True:
        game_start == False
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                done = True

            SCREEN.fill(GREY)

            for Menu in help_:
                if Menu.rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
                    Menu.hovered = True
                else:
                    Menu.hovered = False
                Menu.draw()

            for Menu in quit_:
                if Menu.rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
                    Menu.hovered = True
                    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                        done = True
                else:
                    Menu.hovered = False
                Menu.draw()

            for Menu in continue_game:
                if Menu.rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
                    Menu.hovered = True
                    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                        game_start = True
                else:
                    Menu.hovered = False
                Menu.draw()

            cube.update()
            cube.draw(SCREEN)

            eye.update()
            eye.draw(SCREEN)

            mood_good.update()
            mood_good.draw(SCREEN)

            if blink == 1:
                blinking.update()
                blinking.draw(SCREEN)

            if event.type == CLOCKTICK:
                blink_clock = blink_clock + 1
                if blink_clock == 1:
                    blink_clock = 0
                    blink = random.randint(0, 1)
                if blink == 1:
                    blinking.update()
                    blinking.draw(SCREEN)
                    if blink_clock == 1:
                        blink = 0

            blankgroup.update()
            blankgroup.draw(SCREEN)

    if game_start == True:
        menu_on = False

        for event in pygame.event.get():

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                 if event.key == pygame.K_p:
                     pause = True
                 else: pause = False

            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                done = True

            elif event.type == CLOCKTICK:
                minute = minute + 1
                if minute == 60:
                    hour = hour + 1
                    minute = 0
                if minute < 60:

                    if hunger > 0:
                        hunger = hunger - 2
                    else: hunger = hunger

                    if fun > 0:
                        fun = fun - 2
                    else: fun = fun

                    if health > 0:
                        health = health - 1
                    else: health = health

                if hour == 24:
                    day = day + 1
                    hour = 0
                if day == 365:
                    year = year + 1
                    day = 0

                blink_clock = blink_clock + 1
                if blink_clock == 1:
                    blink_clock = 0
                    blink = random.randint(0, 1)
                if blink_clock == 1:
                    blink = 0


            SCREEN.fill(WHITE)

            cube.update()
            cube.draw(SCREEN)

            eye.update()
            eye.draw(SCREEN)

            if feeling >= 4:
                mood_good.update()
                mood_good.draw(SCREEN)

            if feeling == 3 :
                mood_fine.update()
                mood_fine.draw(SCREEN)

            if blink == 1:
                blinking.update()
                blinking.draw(SCREEN)

            blankgroup.update()
            blankgroup.draw(SCREEN)

            MINUTEFONT = FONT.render("Minute:{0:02}".format(minute), 1, BLACK)
            SCREEN.blit(MINUTEFONT, MINUTEFONTR)

            HOURFONT = FONT.render("Hour:{0:02}".format(hour), 1, BLACK)
            SCREEN.blit(HOURFONT, HOURFONTR)

            DAYFONT = FONT.render("Day:{0:03}".format(day), 1, BLACK)
            SCREEN.blit(DAYFONT, DAYFONTR)

            YEARFONT = FONT.render("Year:{0:03}".format(year), 1, BLACK)
            SCREEN.blit(YEARFONT, YEARFONTR)

            #Hunger


            HUNGERFONT = FONT_HUD.render("Hunger:{0:03}".format(hunger),1, BLACK)
            SCREEN.blit(HUNGERFONT, HUNGERFONTR)

            if hunger >= 75:
                HUNGERFONT_G = FONT_HUD.render("Hunger:{0:03}".format(hunger),1, GREEN)
                SCREEN.blit(HUNGERFONT_G, HUNGERFONT_RR)
                feeling = feeling + 1
            if hunger <= 25:
                HUNGERFONT_R = FONT_HUD.render("Hunger:{0:03}".format(hunger),1, RED)
                SCREEN.blit(HUNGERFONT_R, HUNGERFONT_GR)
                feeling = feeling - 1
            if hunger == 74:
                feeling = feeling -1

            #Fun

            FUNFONT = FONT_HUD.render("Fun:{0:03}".format(fun),1, BLACK)
            SCREEN.blit(FUNFONT, FUNFONTR)

            if fun >= 75:
                FUNFONT_G = FONT_HUD.render("Fun:{0:03}".format(fun),1, GREEN)
                SCREEN.blit(FUNFONT_G, FUNFONT_RR)
                feeling = feeling + 1
            if fun <= 25:
                FUNFONT_R = FONT_HUD.render("Fun:{0:03}".format(fun),1, RED)
                SCREEN.blit(FUNFONT_R, FUNFONT_GR)

            if fun == 74:
                feeling = feeling -1

            #Health

            HEALTHFONT = FONT_HUD.render("Health:{0:03}".format(health),1, BLACK)
            SCREEN.blit(HEALTHFONT, HEALTHFONTR)

            if health >= 75:
                HEALTHFONT_G = FONT_HUD.render("Health:{0:03}".format(health),1, GREEN)
                SCREEN.blit(HEALTHFONT_G, HEALTHFONT_RR)
                feeling = feeling + 1
            if health <= 25:
                HEALTHFONT_R = FONT_HUD.render("Health:{0:03}".format(health),1, RED)
                SCREEN.blit(HEALTHFONT_R, HEALTHFONT_GR)
                feeling = feeling - 1

            if health == 74:
                feeling = feeling -1
                print(event)

    clock.tick(FPS) 
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate or similar enough to help you?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18968022/why-is-my-pause-system-not-working-pygame?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

The pause should occur from an event.

You want it by a keypress 'P', right?

```
paused = False
while game_loop:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==KEYDOWN:
            if event.key=='P':
                paused = not paused
        //other events
    if paused:
        //draw pause menu here
        pause() //This function will have its own pause loop running until
                //you select an item in the pause menu 
                //and will set paused = not paused on exit
    else:
        //draw main game here
```

This is how you can do it by adding to the main event queue. Always add events in that.

You can check this snake game, too. It has the pause menu in it. Press ESC key for that !

EDIT: Sorry, I didnt provide any link for the snake game. https://github.com/sk364/fun-snake-attack/blob/master/game.py#L508

You can then create a pause menu which will have its own event loop

Comment: @Dygestor Thank you for your help, but now the whole game is frozen or not responsive

Comment: @Relentile I did not answer your question, I only edited the formatting, ask Sachin Kukreja for help :)

Comment: @Sachin Kukreja My game is either frozen or un-responsive?

Comment: @Relentile answer edited. Check the link for more understanding.